# Diskless root filesystem starts to break when copied to a new location

Tags: boot, rsync, cp, root-filesystem, pxe

I am pxe booting using nfs to get a diskless cluster. When doing testing I wanted to make a copy of the directory used by the nodes to mount the linux root filesystem. But after copying the file over and booting to the new root filesystem the node has some issues (services failing to load, ect). It still boots but not clean.

Alpha is the original working directory and beta is the new test destination.

```
works - append initrd=centos7/initrd.img root=nfs:192.168.2.1:/alpha selinux=0 ipv6.disable=1

issues - append initrd=centos7/initrd.img root=nfs:192.168.2.1:/beta selinux=0 ipv6.disable=1
```

My question is how do copy alpha to beta so that it works exactly like before? I'm assuming the problem might have something to do with hard links. I can't think of much else.

```
rsync -av alpha/* beta 

[root@alpha-cm compute]# du -s *
1471008 alpha
1509328 beta

[root@alpha-cm compute]# du -sb *
1445352775  alpha
1467995772  beta
```

Adding -X to rsync didn't help.

```
cp -a alpha beta

[root@alpha-cm compute]# du -s *
1471008 alpha
1470848 beta

[root@alpha-cm compute]# du -sb *
1445352775  alpha
1445291335  beta
```

The second way is very close to the same size but I still have problems when booting into it.

Comment: I tried rsync with -acvAXSH options with no luck..

Comment: It was user error... While editing the pxe boot menu file I accidentally removed rw and so the filesystem was booting read only. Sorry for the unneeded post.